# template rendering is not working properly in ember js

Tags: ember.js

```
        I am very new to Ember js. when i route one template to another it working properly.but the problem is when i was render same template it won't work.

        My code is follows:
```

## index.html:Manager template in index.html

```
              <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="manager">
             {{#each model.manager}}
             <div class="pure-g-r content-ribbon">
                      <div class="pure-u-1-3">
                          <div class="img-viewer-profile">
                              <img {{bindAttr src="image"}}>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="pure-u-2-3">
                          <div class="l-box">
                            <h4 class="content-subhead">{{name}}</h4>
                            <table class="pure-table">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr class="pure-table-odd">
                                  <td>Id</td>
                                  <td><b>ATL-{{id}}</b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pure-table-odd">
                                  <td>Team</td>
                                  <td><b>{{team}}</b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>Division</td>
                                  <td><b>{{division}}</b></br>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="pure-table-odd">
                                  <td>Manager</td>
                                  <td>
                                   <b>
                                   <a href="#" {{action "managerinfo" manager_id}}>
                                    {{manager_name}}
                                    </a>
                                   </b>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                {{/each}}
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>Reportees</td>
                                  <td>
                                  {{#each model.results}}
                                  <br><b>
                                       <a href="#" {{action "profileinfo" id}}>
                                       {{reportees}}
                                       </a>
                                  </b></br>
                                  {{/each}}
                                  </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                {{outlet}}
          </script>

 app.js:
=========
        App.ManagerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

      manager_id: '',
      id: '',
      actions:{
       managerinfo: function(manager_id) {
          // the manager id of selected manager field
          var manager_id = manager_id;
          alert("profile");
          alert(manager_id);

          managerdata = $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/manager?manager_id=" + manager_id,
            async: false}).responseJSON

          managerdata.manger_id = manager_id;
          console.log(managerdata);
          this.transitionToRoute('manager', managerdata);
          }
    )}
```

Now my problem is when render the  new manager data to manager it wont be displayed.
 After refresh only it shows the data.

```
    what mistake i was done in this code , i dont understand.so please provide me solution.
```

i added my complete code here with proper tags order.

Comment: you want to transition to same route with new data??...why??...

Comment: yes because In manager template i displayed manager data and his superior name.when he click on superior(he is also manager ) i need to display his details.thats why i transition to same route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment, the way you are doing is not suggested. You can pass manager_id in the route url. I will give you very basic skeleton which you can make further changes. Do remember, if you want to set model data from ajax, use `model` hook in the route

First Router

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("managers", function(){
    this.route("all");
    this.route("manager", { path: "/:manager_id" });
  });
});
```

So here with `#/manager/all` displays all managers list
`#/manager/:manager_id` displays manager with id manager_id

Next ManagerAll route

```
App.ManagersAllRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    //do ajax and return managers data which sets as model for this route
  }
});
```

sameway

```
App.ManagersManagerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    //do ajax and return managers data which sets as model for this route
    //here params will have the manager_id passed through url
    //as it is ajax, create a promise
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Ember.$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/manager?manager_id=" + params.manager_id,
        async: false}).then(function(data){
          resolve(data);
     })
    });
   }
});
```

Next is template for managers

```
{{#each model.manager}}
    {{#link-to 'managers.manager' manager_id}}{{{manager_name}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

Now a template for manager

```
{{manager_id}}
{{manager_name}} blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the each tag properly.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="manager">
{{#each model.manager}}
    <a href="#" {{action "managerinfo" manager_id}}>
       {{manager_name}}
    </a>
{{/each}}       
</script>
```

Also you haven't closed the ManagerController correctly in the given above. Double check that.

```
 App.ManagerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  manager_id: '',
  id: '',
  actions:{
   managerinfo: function(manager_id) {
      // the manager id of selected manager field
      var self=this;
      var manager_id = manager_id;
      alert("profile");
      alert(manager_id);

      managerdata = $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/manager?manager_id=" + self.manager_id,
        async: false}).responseJSON.then(function(managerdata) {
            managerdata.manger_id = self.manager_id;
            console.log(managerdata);
            this.transitionToRoute('manager', managerdata);
        })
      }
)}
```

Comment: Sorry, just i add some part of my code to here.Thats why i forget to close that.But my application all tags are managed correctly

Comment: Did you add the {{/each}} part?

Comment: Sorry for the screwed up format in the comment. But whats happening is that your asynchronous request comes after you have transitioned to the route. So you have to use a promise, using then keyword so the code is executed after the request comes back. Do everything inside the promise related to the data

Comment: Thank you for the response.but it gives the error "Cannot call method 'then' of undefined "

Comment: I just realized that my solution wouldn't make any sense as you have turned async option in the ajax request to false. So it is actually not an asynchronus request